# Scrollbar para multiples listboxs con tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Gente me ayudan a entender mejor este codigo?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo saqué de esta publicación
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066974/scrolling-multiple-tkinter-listboxes-together

Lo que no entiendo bien es cuales son los argumentos que entran en los metodos de scroll personalizados. Que datos ingresan a estas funciones?

Answer (score 0):

Primero, cuando en Python se pasan argumentos mediante `*args`, lo que hacemos es permitir pasar un numero indeterminado de argumentos no keyword y éstos son agrupados en una tupla. Lo importante es `*`, `args` es solo una convención:

```
def foo(*argumentos):
    print(argumentos)

foo(1, 5, "bar")
```

> (1, 5, 'bar')

La `Listbox` pasa a la callback asignada a `yscrollcomand` dos argumentos, que son dos cadenas de la forma:

```
('0.65', '0.75')
```

Realmente son dos floats, entre o y 1 (normalizados) que representan la **posición** relativa y normalizada de la primera y la última **línea visible** respectivamente.

En tu caso, quieres que al hacer scroll en una de las listas la otra se mueva la par, para ello cundo haces scroll en una lista, mueves la otra también mediante su método`yview_moveto` al que le pasas la posición de la primera linea visible de la `ListBox` en la que el scroll ha tenido lugar (`args[0]`).

Por su parte la barra de scroll pasa a su callback asociada (`self.yview`) argumentos distintos según la situación:

- Cuando se interactúa con ella haciendo click en la barra y arrastrándola manda lo siguiente:

  ```
  ('moveto', '0.39527131782945735')
  ```

  El primer argumento es simplemente el mensaje, generalmente destinado al widget asociado (`Listbox` en este caso). El segundo es la posición a la que debe moverse, que se corresponde con el primer argumento que la `Listbox` pasa a `yscrollcommand` como vimos antes, con una pequeña corrección, la lista ajusta la posición para que la línea se vea completa, corrigiendo la posición de la barra de scroll de ser necesario. Esta es una de las razones de la comunicación mutua entre la barra y el widget.
- Si se hace click o se usa la rueda del ratón en la ScrollBar pero fuera de la barra, se genera un evento de scroll:

  ```
  ('scroll', '1', 'pages')
  ('scroll', '5', 'units')
  ```

  En este caso el primer argumento indica el evento simplemente, el segundo es el valor y el tercero las unidades, que puede ser  'pages' o 'units'. En el caso de 
  `('scroll', '5', 'units')` le indica a la `Listbox` que se desplace 5 "unidades" hacia abajo, lo que generalmente es desplazarse 5 lineas.